# sproutcore upgrade issues

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

I got weird issues when I upgraded my sproutcore app from 1.6.0.rc1 to newer versions.

my app becomes unrepsonsive, hangs, works sometimes.

What is causing this and what to do about it?

Comment: How did you upgrade? Do you have a sproutcore directory in your app's framework folder?

Comment: rvm gem install sproutcore, no i dont have sproutcore directory in my apps folder. I just followed the documentation.

Comment: removing all caches everywhere and tmp directory when i use sc-server seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the default Ruby development server.

sc-server create's a tmp directory in your project. Delete it after an upgrade and clear all you browser cache and my problems dissapeared.

Also I have heard if you use garcon, a javascript based development server. Then you avoid these problems.